# New Outlook on Mac OS does not create log file

Tags: macos, outlook, ms-office, outlook-2016

I have updated my outlook to v16.46 and it introduce the new switch "New Outlook". If I enable this switch the log file i.e. *.olk15Message file does not store locally. If I disable this switch then all log files get created.

[image]

I would like to backup all Folders/Mails that are stored locally. But if this feature is enable I am not getting the my mail files.

Does any one have any idea where these olk15Message file gets stored when "New Outlook" switch is enable.

Comment: OS Version?  The log might be in the app container `~/Library/Containers`.

Comment: OS version is macOS Catalina i.e. v10.15.7. When the "New Outlook" switch is disable the logs are stored in "~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages" directory.

Comment: This is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Questions on general usage of Microsoft Word should be asked on an appropriate end-use forum (e.g., MS Answers).

Comment: @macropad, I have written a code to read that log files and take a backup. It is working fine when log file exist. The problem is not in code. The problem is Outlook introduce new feature i.e "New Outlook" switch in v16. If this switch is enable then the log file is not getting created locally. In previous version of outlook or if you disable this switch then you will get all log files in "~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/Outlook/Outlook 15 Profiles/Main Profile/Data/Messages" directory.